# What is the dotnet equivalent for the jquery $.exends method

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, vb.net, object

I would like to merge two C#/VB.NET objects! In jquery, you write:

```
   var merged= $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

Have you ever written a method or class that returns the same result as [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method in dotnet? Or it exists please share it with me.

Comment: What are the types of the objects?

Comment: I assume the outcome is a dynamic object? Or is it a dictionary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396422/c-sharp-merge-two-objects-together-at-runtime?lq=1
You have to use search before posting!

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with the same object types, you can add two lists with the [.AddRange()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method (as long as you're using the Collections namespace).

Something along the lines of:

```
List<Thingamajigs> myNewListOfThingamajigs = thingamajigs1.AddRange(thingamajigs2);
```